# Outgoing Telnet fails however ping works

Tags: telnet, opc

We have an OPC Server running on windows server 2003. I am using an OPC client from a remote machine running on Windows Server 2008.

From the OPC Server node, I can ping the Client node. However I am not able to telnet ( I tried only port 135 which is for DCOM communication).

Any other machine can telnet the client machien i.e. Windows Server 2008.

I see on OPC Server, the port 135 is added.

One more thing, the tracert doesn't fully show all the hops from OPC Server to OPC Client.

I can telnet from OPC Client to OPC Server on port 135.

Do you think port 135 communication is blocked when the telnet packet routes from OPC Server to OPC Client ?

Please reply . Its driving me crazy. DCOM headache !!

Comment: why do you need to access the client, the whole idea is that the client connects to the server, whether you can telnet the client or not seems not so important? if the client has some firewall it could prevent access.

Comment: Apparently there seems to be something wrong with the OPC server itself. We ran one OPC Client right on the OPC Server node and found out that the connection gets disconnected after about 3 minutes. If anything else comes up, I will post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a firewall problem. You always have to make sure port 135 is open on both the sides. Use telnet to verify port before dealing with DCOM issues.